# How to add all git tags from other branch?

Tags: git, github

How get all git tags from my develop branch into my main branch

Does merging not auto import them?

I am using below to check if its added

```
git tag --sort=creatordate -l core-crm_v3.2* --merged
```

Comment: The tags are references to commits. When merging, the result is another commit with the combination of both branches. Nevertheless, the tags still point to the previous old commits.

Comment: A tag is a reference to a commit.  A branch is a reference to a commit (and some metadata). If the commit referenced by a tag is not an ancestor of the commit referenced by main, it's not on the branch.  If you move the tag so that it refers to a commit on the main branch, then it no longer references its previous commit.  Or are you asking how to fetch tags from a remote?